# Error didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-views

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator
from . models import Tip
from . choices import categoría_choices

def buscar(request):
    queryset_list = Tip.objects.order_by('-list_date')

        #Keywords
    if 'keywords' in request.GET:
     keywords = request.GET['keywords']
     if keywords:
      queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(descripción__icontains=keywords)

    #Categoría
    if 'categoría' in request.GET:
     categoría = request.GET['categoría']
     if categoría:
      queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(categoría__iexact=categoría)

      context = {
          'categoría_choices': categoría_choices,
          'tips': queryset_list,
          'values': request.GET 
          }
      return render(request,'tips/buscar.html', context)
```

El error que me aparece es ValueError: The view tips.views.buscar didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Cuando busco en el buscador con keywords (sin agregar las categorías) o busco solo sin agregar alguna variable en el buscador. Forzosamente requiere que marque la categoría para que no aparezca error, ¿
¿Podrían apoyarme en solucionar este error?

Comment: y si la url tiene  una keywords y una categoria, solo mostraría resultado de categoría

Answer (score 0):

Si tu codigo esta bien indentado en la publicacion, se ve como que el context y el return render esta adentro de un if por eso retorna None, dejalo asi:

```
def buscar(request):
    queryset_list = Tip.objects.order_by('-list_date')

    #Keywords
    if 'keywords' in request.GET:
        keywords = request.GET['keywords']
        if keywords:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(descripción__icontains=keywords)

    #Categoría
    if 'categoría' in request.GET:
        categoría = request.GET['categoría']
        if categoría:
        queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(categoría__iexact=categoría)

    context = {
        'categoría_choices': categoría_choices,
        'tips': queryset_list,
        'values': request.GET 
    }
    return render(request,'tips/buscar.html', context)
```

de esta manera si no recibe ningun filtro por GET va a devolver `queryset_list = Tip.objects.order_by('-list_date')` por defecto.